# jQuery - Call a function on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I  want to call a function to show and modify content like this:

```
$('#element').someFunction();
```

I wrote this function:

```
function someFunction(){
     $(this).show();
     //other stuff
}
```

But this don't work. 
Can someone give me a hint how to solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could [extend jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) and create a custom method:

```js
$.fn.someFunction = function() {
  return this.hide();
};

$('.element').someFunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">This should be hidden.</div>
<div class="element">This should be hidden.</div>
```

Internally `.hide()` will iterate over each element, but if you want to do this manually, you could just utilize the `.each()` method:

```
$.fn.someFunction = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    // 'this' refers to the element here
  });
};
```

Comment: Works great!Thank you!